# Error consulta sql oracle

Tags: java, oracle

Tengo un aplicación java que se conecta por JDBC y hago esta consulta:

Mi codigo :

```
String date = "21-Dec-16";
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("SELECT * ");
query.append("FROM TEST WHERE PUBLISHED_DATE='").append(date).append("'");
connection = getConnection(jdbc);
stmt = connection.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query.toString());

syso query => select * from TEST where PUBLISHED_DATE='21-Dec-16'
```

y el error que obtengo:

```
java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

TB he probado:

```
select * from TEST where PUBLISHED_DATE=TO_DATE('21-Dec-16','DD-MON-RR')
```

y el error:

```
java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

Sin embargo, ejecuto la misma consulta en mi sql developer y funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te funciona en tu SQL-Developer y no cuando lo lanzas mediante tu aplicación, se debe a que la sesión que abre SQL-Developer está configurada con un lenguaje y formato de fecha diferentes a la sesión que abres desde tu aplicación.

Puedes consultar los parámetros de tu sesión con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM nls_session_parameters;
```

La información que te interesará es `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` y `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE`, aunque si no lo conocías, es conveniente que eches un vistazo al resto de parámetros (`NLS_LANGUAGE`, `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`, etc.)

En tu caso, cuando comparas o conviertes cadenas a fecha, tienes que tener en cuenta esta configuración.

Comentas por ejemplo que al lanzar esta consulta, recibes un error de que el mes no es válido:

```
select * from TEST where PUBLISHED_DATE=TO_DATE('21-Dec-16','DD-MON-RR')
```

Esto se debe a que Dec es el acrónimo de **Dec**ember y si te funciona en SQL-Developer, se debe a que `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` está configurado para mostrar los nombres de los meses en inglés (`AMERICAN`).

Si no te funciona en tu aplicación, se debe a que `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` lo tendrás configurado para mostrar los nombres de los meses en castellano (`SPANISH`), por lo que realmente tendrías que haber escrito 21-**Dic**-16 (de **Dic**iembre).

Estos valores puedes modificarlos con el comando `ALTER SESSION SET Option=Value` o puedes pedirle a tu DBA que te lo configure. Te dejo un [enlace](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_options067.htm#OLADM408).

Answer (score 0):

Este error es causado porque la fecha se envía como string el la consulta, y el programa espera recibir una valor numérico, es decir, un número, como recomendación es que cambies o la fecha a una `string` o cambies el valor recibido a una `string` de esta forma recibirás el mismo dato y no debería saltar el error. Si pones más código podré darte una valoración más detallada.

Comment: pregunta actulizada con lo que me pides

Comment: @sirdaiz puedes probar a cambiar a un string o puedes poner `java.sql.Timestamp`